# SVM Regularization Term(C) = (1/lambda) vs 1/(2*lambda)

Tags: machine-learning, svm, regularization

The way I learned SVM Cost Function from Andrew ng Coursera was:

$$ J = \sum_{i=1}^my*Cost_1(z) + (1-y)*Cost_0(z) + \frac{\lambda}{2}*\sum_{j=1}^n\theta^2$$
which further simplifies with parameter $ C = \frac{1}{\lambda}$:
$$ J = C*\sum_{i=1}^my*Cost_1(z) + (1-y)*Cost_0(z) + \frac{1}{2}||\theta||^2$$
where 
$$ z = \theta^TX \space\space\space \text{(weights * input)} $$ 
$$ Cost_0(z) = max(0,1+z) $$
$$ Cost_1(z) = max(0,1-z) $$

I then encountered a similar form of equation on wikipedia:

$${\displaystyle \left[{\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}\max \left(0,1-y_{i}({\vec {w}}\cdot {\vec {x}}_{i}-b)\right)\right]+\lambda \lVert {\vec {w}}\rVert ^{2},}$$

Acknowledging the notation differences, My only problem with this definition is in the regularization term, where it is missing $\frac{1}{2}$. Because of this, it seems to suggest me that $C = \frac{1}{2*\lambda}$, if I try to make sense of the Wikipedia definition out of what I learned from Andrew Ng Course.

I understand that 1/2 is just a scale and most likely not affect the decision made by SVM - I may be thinking wrong - but I still want to understand the reason anyone would go with the later equation.

Thank you.